# How to find unique rows from a Ruby variable containing database rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have these line of code in Ruby:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver, suite, date from mastertest order by date desc limit 30")
```

So mastertest contains all the rows from my database table.

I want only all rows which have a unique value of code_ver from the results. How do I find that ?

Comment: is this an SQL question? `select code_ver, suite, date from mastertest group by code_ver`

Comment: This won't work as I have a order by clause in the query too.

Comment: @shime: That query will fail in most databases since you're selecting things that aren't grouped or used in aggregate functions.

Comment: @muistooshort cool, thanks. :) my sql skills are pretty rusty, but I gave it a shot.

Comment: You want to find all the rows whose `code_ver` values appears exactly once in the entire table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select distinct code_ver, suite, date from mastertest where code_ver = "#{@variable}")
```

Comment: this doesn't work as I have a order by clause at the end which sorts them by date

Comment: added a 'where' clause so you can filter via a ruby variable - check the edited code above.